# On Click toggle only between checked or unchecked state for a tristate datagridcheckbox column

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridcheckbox column with tristate enabled with values true state =2, false state=0 and intermediate state =1 which will be toggled between the three states programatically which is done. 
        But on click I should allow to toggle between checked or uncheck only but not to intermediate state, which I am unable to get the solution. If any friends can help me out of this ... please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CheckChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event to intercept the click and than toggle the value between the two states you require.